# Find all id's where date value is null

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a list of UserID's where every entry for them has an EndDate of NULL For instance

```
Userid | EndDate
123    | NULL
123    | NULL
124    | 2016-01-01
124    | NULL
123    | NULL
123    | NULL
125    | 2016-01-01
126    | NULL
```

So I only want to return 123 and 126.

It seems like there would be a somewhat simple way to do this, but I am not coming up with it.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What's the problem? `WHERE EndDate IS NULL`

Comment: I just want a list of all the UserID's have ALL Null Entries, 124 has one NULL and one Date, 125 has no NULL's but a date. 123 and 126 have all NULL's so I want to extract them.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Userid 
from sometable
group by Userid
having count(EndDate) = 0
```

http://rextester.com/QJSWV55265

`count(EndDate)` will return `0` if only NULL values are present for that `Userid`.

If you have a `users` table and proper indexes, that one might be faster:

```
select Userid
from users u
where not exists (
    select *
    from sometable t
    where t.Userid = u.Userid
    and t.EndDate is not null
)
```

**UPDATE** The opposite query (get `Userid` when all entries ar not null) would be:

```
select Userid 
from sometable
group by Userid
having count(EndDate) = count(Userid)
```

http://rextester.com/FUKPLP59441

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the help here, one quick follow up. What if I wanted the opposite:
    Userid | EndDate
    123    | 2016-01-01
    123    | NULL
    124    | NULL
    124    | 2016-01-01
    123    | 2016-01-01
    123    | NULL
    125    | 2016-01-01
    126    | NULL

where I wanted to pull 125 and 124 because ALL the values are not null, 126 has only one NULL and 123 has one value that is not null...

Comment: @KLD You can change the HAVING clause to `having count(EndDate) = count(Userid)`. Or take the second query (or one of the other two answers) and change `t.EndDate is not null` to `t.EndDate is null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all the userIDs that have a non-null end date, then use `NOT IN` to exclude them.

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid
FROM yourTable
WHERE userid NOT IN (
    SELECT userid
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE EndDate IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` and a subquery to do this:

```
select distinct
    `userid`
from yourtable t1
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from yourtable t2 
  where t1.userid = t2.userid 
  and t2.enddate is not null
)
```

and [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15220/1) here.